# check whether the characteristics functions of the set $ \ X \ $ is Surjective?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If $ X \subset Y \ $ with $ \ X \neq \phi \ $ , then check whether the characteristics functions of the set $ \ X \ $ is Surjective ?

**Answer:**
We know

$ \large \chi_{X } : Y \to \{0,1 \} \ $ .

Now if $ X=Y=singleton \ set \ $ , then $ |X|=|Y|=1 \ $,

But $ |\{0,1\}|=2 \ $,

Hence $ \chi_X \ $ can not be surjective.

**I need confirmation of my work .**

Comment: Your reasoning is okay if $\subset$ stands for "subset of". Not if it stands for "proper subset of".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $X\subset Y$ stands for $X$ is a *proper* subset of $Y$ and the domain of the characteristic function is $\{0,1\}$ then, since $X\neq\varnothing$ the function is surjective.

It will take value $1$ for every $x\in X$ and such $x$ exists.

It will take value $0$ for every $x\in Y-X$ and such $x$ exists.

---

If $X\subset Y$ stands for $X$ is a subset of $Y$ then the function is surjective if $X\neq Y$ (then $X$ is a proper set of $Y$ and we are back in the first case) and is not surjective if $X=Y$ (then it will not take value $0$).

So in that case the statement that the function is surjective is not true in general.

Comment: But if $ X=Y \ $ , then still it will hold or not ? because here $ \subset \ and \ \subseteq \ $ are same notation

Comment: I have edited. Is everything clear now? Btw be careful with notations $\subset$ and $\subseteq$. If both are used then that is an indication that they are not the same. If only $\subseteq$ is used then everything is clear( recommendable). If only $\subset$ is used then that is an indication that it stands for "subset of" and not "proper subset of". Always check what side the author is on.

Comment: yes , it is clear now